# How to pass the value inside Rotativa.ActionAsPdf

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I am new asp .net .

I am using Rotativa to turn a Razor view into a PDF.

I am having a normal preview page which is working fine.

The same thing I want to print in PDF .

```
       [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult IdCardPreview(string empid)
    {

        int empid1 = Convert.ToInt32(empid);
        var dataList = db.mstEmpInformations.Where(x => x.intEmpId == empid1).SingleOrDefault();

        return View(dataList);
    }


   public ActionResult GeneratePDF(string empid)
    {
        int empid1 = Convert.ToInt32(empid);

        return new Rotativa.ActionAsPdf("IdCardPreview", new { empid1 });
    }
```

while running the generate pdf is is showing the error as **Object reference not set to an instance of an object.**

Can any1 tell how i can pass the empid from generate pdf to IDCardpreview ?

Answer (score 1):

The code should look like this at the generatePDF Action.

```
public ActionResult GeneratePDF(string empid)
{
    return new Rotativa.ActionAsPdf("IdCardPreview", new { empid = empid });
}
```

Rotavita is going into the IdCardPreview action itself, and the conversion from string to int will be at the IdCardPreview Action.